# Setting out lstm dense parameter

Tags: python, lstm

I'm trying to figure out how the parameter which goes under "dense" should be set, i.e. Dense(10) below
How is this value arrived at or is it somewhat arbitrary ?
   `model = Sequential([ Dense(32, input_shape=(784,)), Activation('relu'), Dense(10), Activation('softmax'),`

I havent tried anything. Its more of a theoretical question rather than practical.